# RabbitMQ - Can i publish an event from different exchange

Tags: rabbitmq

Here's an example:

```
TYPE : TOPIC

exchange.v1 -> queue.order
exchange.v2 -> queue.log
```

so when the apps running it's must configure the exchange first right? and in a single service only can have 1 exchange?

I have 1 service for logging and 1 service for ordering. all proses will be sent into logging service and then forward another event. in this case to queue.order

**So it's possible to publish an event from a different exchange?** or I miss something? please let me know :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exchanges are not tied to “services”, much less in a 1:1 manner.

Exchanges in RabbitMQ are message sinks. Any existing exchanges can be published to by any number of applications (“services”) with adequate permissions.

Exhanges can either be pre-deployed or created automatically by an application. Pre-deployment is usually more common. This may or may not be outside the lifecycle of a single “service”.

Exchanges (depending on type) may also route to any number of queues on the same vhost.

Now, with all of that out of the way..

It is very possible to forward a message from a queue to another exchange: read from queues (stores), publish to exchanges (sinks). This can be done in code or even from a tool like the Shovel plugin - the “correct” approach depends significantly based on semantics, just as the choice of routing.

Personally, I recommend keeping RabbitMQ processing chains to as limited a scope as allowed by the application domain.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering my question. Can u give me some reference so I can read more detail about it? like a link doc or something

Comment: https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html is a general concept overview of the conceptual model. There is lots of additional documentation on the site.